# Given a finite set of group generators (via a group action on a finite set of objects), can we enumerate the group easily?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, formal-languages, formal-grammar

I have a clearly finite set of objects $S$ (single-string grammars of a strings $s$ over alphabet $\Sigma$, and a set of generators that generate what I call the **smallest grammar algorithm group**, $G$.

For the purpose of determining the size of $G$ (which might be huge), I would like to perform actions of the generators $g$ on the input string $s$. Yes, $Gs$ the orbit of $G$ on $s \in S$, is indeed all of $S$, so perhaps $S$ is not *all* single-string grammars, but only at least the ones we need to consider).

So for the purpose of computing $|G|$ and potentially $S$ itself, how do I enumerate the elements of $G$ by acting on $s$ with various combinations of the generators?

Is there a simple algorithm to do that?

Comment: There is an algorithm that computes the order (and much more) of any finite permutation group. Since your set of objects is finite, I would assume that you should be able to use this result.

Comment: @Qudit missing a link!

Comment: @Qudit the much more I hope is to list the elements of the group?

Comment: @FruitfulApproach, please note that if the group is huge, listing the elements could be unpractical. But calculating the order is a much simpler task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm mentioned by @Qudit is called [Schreier-Sims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schreier%E2%80%93Sims_algorithm).

[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) and [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/) have the algorithm built in, please try and let us know.